# Is there an alternative to const_cast<char*> within the function findx()?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I am trying to implement a function with the following signature: `char* findx (const char* s, const char* x)`, where the two arguments are C-style strings and the return value is a pointer to the first occurrence of `x` in `s`.

Here is my implementation:

```
char* findx (const char* s, const char* x) {
    // check if s and x valid pointers
    assert(s);
    assert(x);

    // get lengths of s and x
    size_t len_s = m_strlen(s);
    size_t len_x = m_strlen(x);

    // check if x substring (or equal to) of s
    assert(len_s >= len_x);

    char* p_to_match = nullptr;

    // traverse s
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len_s; ++i) {

        if (*(s + i) == *x) {
            p_to_match = const_cast<char*>(s + i);
            //-----------^ can't assing const char* to char* ???

            if (len_x == 1) return p_to_match;

            // the current s's matched the x's zeroth, so next test is for the next elements
            const char* next_s = (s + i + 1);
            const char* first_x = (x + 1);

            for (size_t j = 0; j < len_x - 1; ++x) {
                // if any of the rest of x's elements don't match, break the inner for loop
                if (*(next_s + j) != *(first_x + j)) break;

                // if all the rest of x's elements match return ref_to_match
                if (j == len_x - 2) return p_to_match;
            }
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

The issue I have is that I don't like explicit type casting (`const_cast<char*>`) and I want to replace it with something else, however currently I can't see how to do it without changing either the return value (to `const char*`) or the argument (to `char* s`), so my question is:

Is there a way to implement the function, specifically the return variable, without `const_cast<char*>`, without changing the function signature?

Comment: IMO, the caller should be one who does the cast.

Comment: Side note: you take `const char*` as parameters and you return `char*`. So conceptually you allow to change underlying value of `char*`. But if it is a part of `const char*` then you also allow yourself to change `const char*`. This is conceptually wrong. You should either make them all const or all non-const if you want to keep them related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make `p_to_match` and result type of function `const char*`. You can't return `char*` to point to string that you have as `const char*` without const_cast

If it was possible, you would be able to allow to write (non-const char* return type) to your argument which is `const` (by passing findx(s, s) for example). It would mean there is no point at `const` at all

You may also want to return `char*` when `s` is `char*` and `const char*` when `s` is `const char*`. You may use two separate functions for that or template.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. So, I should overload the function on `const`ness to provide both returning types depending on the arguments, right ?

Comment: Yes, you may overload them or use a template. Overloading is better interface to show that you really have 2 implementations(and not for each type), with template it's easier to share code